# Pass properties to less function

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to write a mixin which handles different screen sizes.  I want to make it as generic as possible to try follow the DRY principle.

So far I have tried:

```
.vary_width(@prop, @val1, @val2, @val3) {
    @media(max-width: 1023px) {
        @{prop}: @val1;
    }
    @media(min-width: 1024px) {
        @{prop}: @val2;
    }
    @media(min-width: 1080px) {
        @{prop}: @val3;
    }
}
```

This is failing to compile.  I have also tried a suggestion (although I think it was aimed at a less version >1.4) to use use the `Ignore: ~"a;@{prop}:@{value}";` command, this is not working either, compiling with to `Ignore: a;margin: 5px;` in CSS.

Many thanks.

Edit:
The error being received when running `lessc master.less master.css`:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in /path/to/file/mixins.less on line 46, column 16:
45     @media(max-width: 1023px) {
46         @{prop}: @val1;
47     }
```

Comment: Well, your code is valid in Less since v1.6.x (provided you use it properly). So if it fails you're most likely using some outdated or non-conformant compiler. Also the hack `Ignore: ~"a;@{prop}:@{value}";` is supposed to compile to `Ignore: a;margin: 5px;` (Browsers will just ingnore unknown `Ignore` property thus the result is actually equal to `margin: 5px;`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I've installed less using npm.  After install displays <code>less@2.5.3</code>.  <code>lessc -v</code> outputs <code>1.4.2</code>.  Getting parseError - will edit the question to include that

Comment: It looks like you're mixed up in "local"/"global" npm installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong version of lessc.  Credit to @seven-phases-max for the guidance.